# Firebase subscribe to a topic dynamically

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a scenario in my app such that, a certain event occurs and I have a list of user-id/tokens and I need to send the notification to all of those n devices.
To trigger the `fcm` with n tokens , n time will not be feasible
so I should create a topic dynamically and subscribe those n users's device id/ token to that topic.

I know I can do it from the client app , but is it possible to do that from backend.
I am using Phoenix as my backend.

Comment: "To trigger the fcm with n tokens , n time will not be feasible" Why not?

Comment: isnt it better to send one topic message instead of n token? or both of those take same complexity?

Comment: You already have the tokens, so it might be simpler to just send to them directly.

Comment: ok, means sending 100 messages to token doesnt have extra over head than a topic with 100 subscribed users, right? @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: A topic is just an automatic fanout to those same tokens. On a delivery level nothing changes, it's just Google's servers doing the fanout from topic to token, vs you doing it in your own code.

Comment: ok thanks for the doubt clearance

Answer (score 1):

*I found the way, writing this answer in case it help others in future*

> Yes Its possible to create a topic dynamically if we have the list of
>   `valid registration token`s

**This is the endpoint url if you want to generate a topic , given you have a list of users-**

```
https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1:batchAdd
```

**The Authorization header contains-**

```
Content-Type- application/json
Authorization- key=<your-server-key>
```

**The body parameters look like-**

```
{
"to": "/topics/<topic name>",
    "registration_tokens": [
        "token1",
        "token2"
    ]
}
```

*And now the topic is created,*

**You can easily sen message to that topic with-** `https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send`

**Authorization token is same as previous one**

**And body as-**

```
{
"priority": "HIGH",
    "notification": {
        "title": "New Text Message",
        "image": "https://firebase.google.com/images/social.png",
        "body": "Hello how are you?"
    },
    "to": "/topics/<topic name>"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> To trigger the fcm with n tokens , n time will not be feasible

Using topics does not inherently change how FCM message delivery works. When you use a topic, the Google servers keep a mapping of that topic to the subscribed tokens. So when you call the API to send a message to a topic, the Google servers fan-out from that topic to the tokens, and then deliver the message with the same infrastructure as when you call the API with the tokens yourself.

Since you already have the tokens, so it might be simpler to just send to them directly, rather than creating a one-off topic.

Comment: but wouldnt it be inefficient if 100 users are there , there will be 100 post requests vs 1 post requests for a topic, just asking, as we should minimize requests to web server

Comment: If you're sending the same message to 100 users, you can pass those tokens in a single request. That's what topics also do.

Comment: yes thats what i wanted to know, that topic message minimizes the no of post requests, rwhich we should keep in mind, right?